# C# js Append version also for files which are used in imports

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp-append-version

I am on c# .net core 2.2 webapp
I am using [asp-append-version="true"] in cshtml for js and css for cache-bursting.
But the issue is i am adding a script like

```
    <script src="~/js/Video/Video.js" type="module" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

The video.js file has following code basically it has some imports

```
import { TestCongestionHeaderInfo } from '../TestCongestionHeaderInfo.js';
import { ResponseHandler } from '../Common/ResponseHandler.js';
...
```

I do get versioning for video.js but not for the imported module files.
Following is the screentshot from chrome Network inspect window

[image]

How can i achieve versioning for the imported files also?

Comment: Well, basically you need to add asp-append-version also for the imported files. I assume that you add them with script tag to your site too, don't you?

Comment: @StanislavBalia, doing so adds two file on ui side 
for e.g 
as in the above problem statement i am using vide.js in cshtml as per your suggestion if i am adding TestCongestionHeaderInfo.js and ResponseHandler.js in cshtml as a script with asp-append-version i am gettin two files for each on ui side

Like 
1. **TestCongestionHeaderInfo.js** and 
    **TestCongestionHeaderInfo.js?v=70Q539HoF(version)**
2. **ResponseHandler.js** and 
    **ResponseHandler.js?v=70Q539HoF(version)**

this should not ideally be the case